# vim tabstop settings not taking effect

Tags: vim

> Update: A solution was found using Ingo Karkat's troubleshooting I was able to identify where my settings were being overridden via :verbose sw? sts?  From this I was able to create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` with my own settings.  Finaly a restart of vim made the changes take effect as my :source ~/.vimrc efforts were not enough to load these changes.  In hinsight that was probably because my new settings were not in the vimrc.  Either way the accepted answer is what finaly solved the problems I was having and life can continue as advertised.

I am a new vim user and am strugling to understand how tabstops and softtabstop works.  I have done a bit of reading and decided that I want my settings as follows

```
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
```

Where I am expecting tabs to be 2 spaces however when I add these to my vimrc and resource the .vimrc doing a gg=G inside my python file does not apply the changes I expect, Instead it places 4 spaces on my indents.  If I enter insert mode I also get 4 spaces for a indent.  Am I failing to set these corectly?  I previously had

```
autocmd FileType python set sw=4
autocmd FileType python set ts=4
autocmd FileType python set sts=4
```

I am thinking maybe this setting is still in the system even after removing it and reloading the vimrc.  I tryed adding

```
autocmd FileType python sw=2 sts=2 ts=2 et
```

However this fails to correct my problem of getting 4 spaces vs 2.  What am I missing?  Is a plugin possibly overriding this?  I looked inside after/syntax but there is only a html.vim in there.  I have a few plugins:
Vundle, YouCompleteMe, taglist, ultisnips, syntastic, vim-surround

Not sure if any of these could be the cause or how I can troubleshoot this further.  Hoping the vim gods will come to my rescue here.

Comment: What you have should work. Open a python file and what's the output from echo &tabstop, echo &softtabstop ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim can tell you where these settings were last set:

```
:verbose setlocal ts? sts? et? sw?
```

It's likely that your global setting got overwritten by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`. This has the following code (in the latest Vim 8.0):

```
if !exists("g:python_recommended_style") || g:python_recommended_style != 0
    " As suggested by PEP8.
    setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
endif
```

As you can see, by `:let g:python_recommended_style = 0` (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`), you can disable the setting. This conditional guard probably has been introduced because many users complained about the preset. In general, filetype plugins do not have such, but you can always override the settings via a script in the *after directory*:

Put the `:setlocal ts=...` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`. Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType python ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations. As you've mentioned that the `:autocmd` didn't work for you, there may be additional customizations (the `:verbose setlocal` should tell you). In that case, you need to find a special solution, depending on what plugin is involved.

Comment: Thank you this is a huge help, those :verbose commands have indeed identified /vim/vim80/ftplugin/python.vim as being the culprits.  I Am running out of time today as I wont be back till Monday, I will respond at that time.  But I did try all your sugestions, its not fixed yet but I am very hopeful that using your sugestions I will get the problem solved.  Wish I had more time today.  Thank you kindly.

Comment: Today I return and was able to get the changes to take effect after restarting vim.  I have accepted your answer and am very grateful for your help in solving this problem I was having.